# Transform argument before passing to a function without use of a closure in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, underscore.js

From time to time I find myself with the following pattern in node.

```
var foobar = function(x, y) {
  foo(x, bar(y));
};
```

You can imagine that you might see this pattern as an anonymous closure that calls a callback function `foo` after performing a transformation `bar` on the result.

```
... , function(err, result) {
    callback(err, transform(result));
} ...
```

My question; is there a way to simplify this pattern in an elegant way?  Ideally it wouldn't need a new utility function (as below) to work, but leverage underscore (or similar).

---

#### Attempted Solution

The composition of `foo` with `bar` is close (which lead me to consider a variant of underscore's `_.compose`), but the transformed value is only one of the arguments passed to `foo`.

My inelegant solution that requires a new utility function (and probably doesn't work for non-primitive arguments) is:

```
function partialCompose(func, transform, position) {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 3);
    args[position] = transform(args[position]);
    return func.apply(this, args);
}

//usage
var foobar = partialCompose.bind(this, foo, bar, 1)
```

Personally I think this is worse in terms of clarity than the original pattern.  Can anyone improve on this? It feels like it should be relatively simple and I missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently found the library [Ramda](http://ramdajs.com/):

> A practical functional library for Javascript programmers.

My early impression seems to be that it is an attempt to extend and improve on libraries such as underscore and lodash, while sticking more strictly to a purely functional style.  Conveniently Ramda includes `useWith` which solves a generalised version of my original problem.  It is described as:

> Accepts a function `fn` and any number of transformer functions and returns a new function. When the new function is invoked, it calls the function `fn` with parameters consisting of the result of calling each supplied handler on successive arguments to the new function.

In other words my original `foobar` pattern becomes:

```
//transform the 1st passed argument with R.identity()
//and the 2nd with bar(), pass the results to foo

var foobar = R.useWith(foo, R.identity, bar);
```

I'm still not aware of a way that this can be achieved out-of-the-box with underscore or lodash, which means for now at least, Ramda is worth investigating further.